# Test events were not received Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing

I am facing this message when I am trying to run the tests from this project, the thing is that we are a lot of persons working on this project and the only one facing this issue is me, even with the latest changes of the code, so it must be an Android Studio cofiguration, I have tried this [Why does Android Studio say “Test events were not received”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394256/why-does-android-studio-say-test-events-were-not-received/30467737), this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795263/test-events-were-not-received-when-run-tests-using-intellij), and this one [No tests were found / Test events were not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400250/no-tests-were-found-test-events-were-not-received), all of them without results, can somebody help me with this?

Comment: This seems to be a more general intellij/gradle problem not limited to android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795263/test-events-were-not-received-when-run-tests-using-intellij?noredirect=1&lq=1